# How can I extend the trial period of applications in Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

In Windows, we can extend the trial period of an app by deleting registry in regedit. Likewise, how can we extend trial period of any app in Ubuntu?

Comment: Which software are you referring to? In many cases free alternatives are available.

Comment: @Zanna Why was this reopened without any details added as to which application this is for? How can this be possibly answered with any degree of clarity then? Here we already have three users guessing in three different directions.

Comment: @muru I think the OP implies that they have a method that works for *any* application in Windows. If there is no such method in Ubuntu, the fact that there is no such method can be the answer. But anyway, the question got closed again.

Comment: @Zanna I'd say OP is a bit behind the times in that case. The registry method of storing trial period information was the norm 10-15 years ago, these days it's not unusual to see asking for credit card information or tying the system to an online check instead - neither of which are defeated by deleting registry keys.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove its WINEPREFIX directory.  Exact directory name and location depends on how did you installed the application:

- for `winetricks` it is usually at `~/.local/share/wineprefixes/` and `winetricks` allows one to remove the prefix by itself;
- for `wine` it is `~/.wine`, be careful here as it may be shared by several applications;
- for PlayOnLinux it is `~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/` and PoL can remove the prefix by itself.

And then reinstall the application.